# Possible to access and backup a corrupted USB HDD via terminal?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, usb

**TL;DR** Is there any way to skip any checks on a corrupted USB disk, "raw mount" the device and create a raw image using macOS terminal tools?

**Details:**

An old Windows notebook of a friend crashed and cannot be booted any more. I extracted the HDD from the notebook and connected it to a PC using an adapter.

Windows is able to detect the HDD and show its volumes. However, the Windows `chkdsk` tools reports a lot of errors. I do not really know the Windows tools and before trying any repair, I would like to create raw a 1:1 image. I do not know any Windows tools to do this.

So, I switched to my Mac (to use `dd` for example) but macOS does not even show the device in the Disk Utility. As long as the HDD is connected, Disk Utility does not open. Using `diskutil list` does not return also, when the HDD is connected. As soon as I disconnect the HDD, `diskutil` returns and shows the others volumes. It seems that macOS stumbles over the corrupted filesystem and thus does not properly mount the device.

Is there any way to skip any checks on a corrupted USB disk, "raw mount" the device and create a raw image using macOS terminal tools?

Comment: A Windows tool to do this would be [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd).